# How do I calculate the number of possibilities when there are restrictions?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

If chips come in four colors and are packaged in packs of 50, how many combinations are possible if the pack must contain at least 10 chips of each color? Is there an easy way that doesn't involve writing out all the possibilities?

Comment: Fill your pack with 10 chips of each color, then you have 10 chips left to put in the pack. If we denote a coloring of the ten chips by a string of the form: 00|000|000|00 where the o's are chips and the |'s are the separation between the colors the leftmost get color 1, then come the ones with color 2, etc. then it's clear that there are Binomial (13,3) = 13!/(3! 10!) possibilities.

Comment: Okay. If there were no restrictions, would there just be $4^{50}$ total combinations possible? Assuming we have an infinite number of chips.

Comment: $4^{50}$ counts the number of ways you can go about coloring 50 chips. But many of them lead to the same pack of chips. Take e.g. a coloring where you gave the first 25 chips color 1 and the last 25 chips color 2. Then the coloring where the first 25 chips were given color 2 and the last 25 chips were given color 1 is a different coloring, but the pack of chips made that way would be considered to be identical.

Comment: So then, would it be $\binom{53}{3}$? You're essentially asking for how many solutions (using only positive integers) you have to the equation $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=50$, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right!

Comment: Could this be generalized if you have restrictions? For example if you have to have at least 14 of the first color, 9 of the second, 10 of the third, and 5 of the fourth, would you just add up $14+9+10+5$ and subtract it from $50$ to arrive at $\binom{15}{3}$ possibilities?

Comment: Yes, that will work for the general case with restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

As Count Iblis said:

> Fill your pack with 10 chips of each color, then you have 10 chips left to put in the pack. If we denote a coloring of the ten chips by a string of the form: 00|000|000|00 where the o's are chips and the |'s are the separation between the colors the leftmost get color 1, then come the ones with color 2, etc. then it's clear that there are Binomial (13,3) = 13!/(3! 10!) possibilities.

$$
n = \binom{50-10\cdot4+4-1}{4-1}=\binom{13}{3}=\binom{13}{10}=\frac{13!}{3!10!}=286
$$